# Need help in converting a case expression to decode in oracle

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have this `case` expression in oracle and I want to convert it into `decode` but I am unable to, can someone help me out?

```
CASE 
 WHEN DAYS <= 0 THEN 'Current'
 WHEN (DAYS > 0 and  DAYS < 31) then '01 - 30 Days' 
 WHEN  (DAYS > 30 and  DAYS < 61) then '31 - 60 Days'
 WHEN  (DAYS > 60 and  DAYS < 91) then '61 - 90 Days' 
 ELSE '91+ Days'
END as Days
```

when trying to do decode

> error: missing right parenthesis

I want to know, is there a way to add a condition in decode?

Comment: Please share the full code with `FROM`

Comment: Why would you want to convert something simple & easy to read and maintain to something complex and difficult to understand?

Comment: @Littlefoot i want to increase the performance of my query so i want to make it decode

Comment: DECODE won't increase performance of your query.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `decode` only supports equality conditions, similar to simple `case`, not searched `case` as in your example. Maybe there is a way to convert all of the conditions to some arithmetic formula that will return 1, 2 or 3 and then check for those values, but as Littlefoot mentioned it won't give you any performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's `DECODE()` function only works when your `CASE` expression has equality checks, but not for inequalities.  However, you may shorten your logic a bit:

```sql
CASE WHEN DAYS <= 0 THEN 'Current'
     WHEN DAYS < 31 THEN '01 - 30 Days'
     WHEN DAYS < 61 THEN '31 - 60 Days'
     WHEN DAYS < 91 THEN '61 - 90 Days'
     ELSE '91+ Days' END AS Days
```

Note that I have dropped the lower range check.  It is possible to do this because for each condition, the previous range in the `CASE` expression rules out the possibility of a lower match.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the **decode**, you must first use the **case** to put them in the **with** and then you can use the **decode** in the **select**

```
with Day as
 (select CASE
           WHEN DAYS <= 0 THEN 1
           WHEN DAYS < 31 THEN 2
           WHEN DAYS < 61 THEN 3
           WHEN DAYS < 91 THEN 4
           ELSE 5
         END AS Days
    from dual)

SELECT decode(Days,
              1, 'Current',
              2, '01 - 30 Days',
              3, '31 - 60 Days',
              4, '61 - 90 Days',
              5, '91 + Days') Days
  FROM day
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.